# Unable to use Less.Parse using dotless in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, less, dotless

I am following the [instructions for using .less](https://github.com/dotless/dotless/wiki/Using-.less) to minify the css.

I have included the dll and made the `Web.config` changes.

However, when I refer to it in `index.cshtml` as `Less.Parse`, the `Less` namespace is not available and I get the exception "The name `Less` does not exist in the current context."

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved it. It was just missing the parent namespace. Now conversion works like a charm.

```
dotless.Core.Less.Parse(css)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Visual Studio, Web Essentials has support for less.

http://vswebessentials.com/features/less

I often use it for :

- .less to .css preview
- View output from a .less compile
- Extract variables/mixins

After build if you go to Output and select Web Essentials from the 'Show output from:' dropdown, you will see a date, time and the  list of .less files that have compiled.

Comment: I am not using web essentials. Basically I get css as string from data base, I need to parse that using dotless before I put it into the web page in style tag. For that I am not able to use Less namespace to parse the string into normal css. Any ideas??