# convert string to css c#

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I have the below css that come as string from data base

```
string css = "div{width:200px}.abc{color:red}";
```

We will fetch this from database and will dump it in to a style tag in mvc view.
I am getting the string but displaying as below:

```
<style type="text/css">
    "div{width:200px}.abc{color:red}"
</style>
```

Where as it should display as :

```
<style type="text/css">
    div{
        width:200px
      }
   .abc{
     color:red 
    }
</style>
```

Can some body advise how can I achieve this?
I tried with dotless, but not able to use it because of the problem stated here :([Unable to use Less.Parse using dotless in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21162836/unable-to-use-less-parse-using-dotless-in-c-sharp))

Please advise??

Comment: Do you mean the formatting is bad, or the fact that it is between `"` ? If the latter applies, you might try placing it in a literal control? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5536209/how-to-use-razor-like-aspliteral

Comment: Please provide more code to get context. How do you create css? What value are you getting from DB? What error do you see?

Comment: @ Christophe De Troyer, The issue is not just with the "". we may get he less css from database not just pure css. In this case I need to convert less css to normal css. how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working with dotless as below..
     dotless.Core.Less.Parse(css)

The formatting is working but still I add some less css in the database the engine is not parsing to css. For ex:

```
 dotless.Core.Less.Parse("@abc:black")
```

the engine is not parsing this variable to css, it is just returning blank..
any ideas??

Answer (score 1):

You can try following code,

```
<style type="text/css">
   @Html.Raw(css)
</style>
```

Or

```
<style type="text/css">
   @MvcHtmlString.Create(css)
</style>
```

Comment: Please see my comment above, I need to convert less css to css.

Comment: sorry i didnt understand?